# Do beacons work like geo fences and have the same limit of 20?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibeacon, beacon

I read somewhere, that beacons on apple, work in a similar way as geo fences, and there too is a limit of 20 per phone.

Is this the case?

Our use case: We want to send push notifications to users when the app is not running and the phone is not awake (in the pocket). We are thinking of relying on beacons instead of geo fences in order to avoid hitting the limit of 20 fences per phone and having to deal with significant location change function and similar solutions (for now).

Answer (score 1):

Beacons work similar as geofences. You will get notified when entering or exiting a beacon-region (in bluetooth range) and you can also range all beacons around to get their ids.

There is also for CLBeaconRegions the 20 regions limit. See:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423656-startmonitoringforregion
With a combination of monitoring regions and ranging, you could be able to do your stuff even with one region. (Depends heavily on your use case)

If you want to send geo-based notifications, beacons could work for you.

Comment: what if my use case is, they I want to have thousands of beacons across the city? Would this be doable with monitoring regions / ranging?

Comment: Something you have to test.
The thing is, in the background you can monitor for regions without problems. The rangingin background only works, when you ask for background time.
So if between your thousands of beacons, you always have an enter/exit callback, you will get your callback & then can start ranging.
If the beacon regions overlap, you must have different regions to battle this problem.

FYI: If you have thousands of beacons outside, you have to spend some money.

Comment: I am trying to figure out, basically, if it would be worth it to invest in beacons, in order to not have to deal with 20 fence limit. It doesn't quite sound like it?

Comment: The "software only" solution with geofences is much cheaper.
Just think of 1. buying all beacons 2. maintaining thousands of beacons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a limit of max 20 regions (both beacon and geofence combine). 
There are ways you can monitor 1000s of beacons but it depends on the use case.

You can use different wildcards and monitor 1000s of beacons but with some limitations. You have to play with beacon configurations like beacon UDID, major and minor values.

If you are only interested in enter or exit of any of the beacons (and not interested in specific beacon). You can actually just set the same UDID of the all the beacons and only monitor one beacon region will solve your problem.

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion.init(proximityUUID: UUID.init(uuidString: "YOUR_BEACONS_UDID_32_DIGITS")!, identifier: "beacon_region1")
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
```

You can also group the beacons with UDID and Major value.

```
let r1 = CLBeaconRegion.init(proximityUUID: UUID.init(uuidString: "YOUR_BEACONS_UDID_32_DIGITS")!, major: 1000, identifier: "region_1000")
```

So you can monitor 20 groups of beacons in background and each group can have as many beacons as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although CoreLocation APIs limit beacon region monitoring to 20 regions (combined with geofence regions), **you can look for nearly 86 billion different beacon locations** for the purpose of sending notifications to a user.

Yes, that's right.  86 billion -- 85,899,345,920 to be precise. Think that's enough?

The simple technique is to combine beacon monitoring APIs with beacon ranging APIs.    Using monitoring, you can wake up your app in the background when any one of your beacons is detected.  Then using ranging APIs you can read the exact beacon identifiers detected, and send a push notification to the user.  This will all work with the phone still sitting in the user's pocket.

Because each beacon identifier includes a major (0-63355) and a minor (0-63335), you can monitor for the maximum 20 beacon regions with a different ProximityUUID, and get 20 x 65536 x 65536 = 85,899,345,920 different combinations.

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion.init(proximityUUID: UUID.init(uuidString: "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")!, identifier: "beacon_region1")
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
// TODO: repeat the above for up to 19 more regions
```

...

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for beacon in beacons {
    var uuid = beacon.proximityUUID
    var major = beacon.major
    var minor = beacon.minor
    // TODO: Send a unique local notification to the user for this
    //       uuid/major/minor combination identifying a particular place
  }
}
```

There are some limits to this approach.  If your beacons are placed within overlapping radio range of each other (~ 50 meters) then a user dwelling by one beacon for awhile then walking to the one next door will not get a background wakeup unless the beacons are in two different regions.   There are some games you can play to get around this limitation, but for many use cases you don't even need to bother.